# Gracenote Rhythm API - is it possible to stream it with web audio?

Tags: api, audio, web-audio-api, gracenote, internet-radio

I just started to discover interesting **Gracenote Rhythm API** - https://developer.gracenote.com/rhythm-api

It says that it includes metadata, music recognition and an **Internet Radio API**, but I didn't find any possiblity to stream it with for example **Web Audio API**, there's no **MP3** or **OGG** url in response:

```
{
"RESPONSE": [{
    "STATUS": "OK",
    "RADIO": [{
        "ID": "1ce6bca226a53326e7bf343dcd168001"
    }],
    "ALBUM": [{
        "ORD": "1",
        "GN_ID": "19878820-CE6C56D99EC0AAE76E9CAE6BE78DF1C9",
        "TRACK_COUNT": "11",
        "ARTIST": [{
            "VALUE": "The Strokes"
        }],
        "TITLE": [{
            "VALUE": "Is This It?"
        }],
        "TRACK": [{
            "TRACK_NUM": "7",
            "GN_ID": "19878827-EBD633D92DFF541BE3DAAF1256F89E93",
            "TITLE": [{
                "VALUE": "Last Night"
            }]
        }]
    }, {
        "ORD": "2",
        "GN_ID": "254058859-822479DA624C6A3C36345E571D395017",
        "TRACK_COUNT": "11",
        "ARTIST": [{
            "VALUE": "The Black Keys"
        }],
        "TITLE": [{
            "VALUE": "El Camino"
        }],
        "TRACK": [{
            "TRACK_NUM": "1",
            "GN_ID": "254058860-5E702E9D83A960AB46E5A6EEDB21D9DD",
            "TITLE": [{
                "VALUE": "Lonely Boy"
            }]
        }]
    },
...
```

Maybe I'm missing something.. is there a way to stream this so-called "Internet Radio"?

P.S. I've googled some node.js modules related to internet radio and all the things I've found are modules like https://github.com/fwg/node-radio-stream which works with Icecast and Shoutcast..

Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the docs Kosmetika. The Gracenote TechPubs team has taken over responsibility for this and will have professional documentation on the site in the next day or so. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for checking it out. The Rhythm API generates personalized radio channels, which are defined as a sequence of songs. It does not provide playback capability itself.

You can look into streaming audio APIs such as Spotify (http://developer.spotify.com), Rdio (http://developer.rdio.com), Beats Music (http://developer.beatsmusic.com) and others for audio playback.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I must admit that gracenote docs are awful.. very outdated, it's not only about rhythm but webapi as well..